# How do I display the width of a JPanel after using getWidth();?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, width

How would I display the width of a panel after using `getWidth()`?  Can I put it in a `JTextField`/`JTextArea`?  I don't think so, but I'm not sure.

Comment: *"How would I display the width of a panel after using `getWidth()`?"* ***Why*** would you display the width of a panel to the user? They can see how big it is on their screen. **Edit:** *"Can I put it in a `JTextField`/`JTextArea`?"* It's certainly possible to do so, as long as the code is designed properly.

Answer (score 0):

**It is certainly possible to display the panel size in a text component.** You can use `setText(String t)` method to set the display text of a `JTextField` or a `JTextArea`. Try this:

```java
String width = myPanel.getWidth();
myTextField.setText(width);
```

It will display the width of the panel to the user in a JTextField. (Or you can replace the text field to any text components you like)

You can also take a look at these two sections in the *[Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)*: [How to use Top-Level containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) and [Using Text Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html). The *Java Tutorial* is a great official document for Swing developers.